# Is it possible to get the names of all the pages in a spreadsheet without knowing the names?

Tags: node.js, google-sheets-api

I currently have a spreadsheet made up of two sheets "Sheet1" and "Sheet2" I am looking to be able to read all the values in these sheets without explicitly specifying the range (e.g ranges: ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2']), is this possible

```
function datapull(auth) {
  const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth });
  sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchGet({
    spreadsheetId: '1eWstBCdmKtL4Mek14uUWVHYTRFkbKscYVIgn5KJkF3U',
    ranges: ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2']
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err){ 
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return;
    }
    const rows = res.data.values;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res, rows, 2));
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to retrieve all values from a Spreadsheet without using the sheet names like `ranges: ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2']`.
- You want to retrieve the values using the method of spreadsheets.values.batchGet of Sheets API.
- You have already been able to put and get values from Spreadsheet using googleapis of Node.js.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modification points:

- In this case, I used the following flow.

  1. Sheet names are retrieved from all sheets in the Spreadsheet using the method of spreadsheets.get.
  2. Retrieve all values from all sheets using the retrieved sheet names.

     - In this case, the method of spreadsheets.values.batchGet is used.

#### Modified script:

```
function datapull(auth) {
  const spreadsheetId = '1eWstBCdmKtL4Mek14uUWVHYTRFkbKscYVIgn5KJkF3U'; // Please set Spreadsheet ID here.

  const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth });
  sheets.spreadsheets.get( // Added
    {
      spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
      fields: "sheets/properties/title"
    },
    (error, result) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log("The API returned an error: " + error);
        return;
      }
      sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchGet(
        {
          spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
          ranges: result.data.sheets.map(e => e.properties.title) // Modified
        },
        (err, res) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log("The API returned an error: " + err);
            return;
          }
          const rows = res.data.values;
          console.log(JSON.stringify(res, rows, 2));
        }
      );
    }
  );
}
```

#### Note:

- This is a simple sample script. So please modify this for your situation.

#### References:

- [spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)
- [spreadsheets.values.batchGet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize

Comment: This is exactly what i was trying to achieve, thank you for your assistance!

Comment: @Nick Winter-Taia Thank you for your response.